# Kotlin setter breaking encapsulation

Tags: oop, kotlin

I've been very worried about this kind of implementation

```
var stringRepresentation: String
    get() = this.toString()
    set(value) {
        setDataFromString(value) // parses the string and assigns values to other properties
    }
```

For me, it takes the assurance of who is assigning the value, because the outsider does not expect this behavior in the class, just want to set a value to that field.

In this case, I'd rather call one function to assign the value and another to call what needs to be called. Or just call a function with a good name that changes the value and does what it needs.

Is this kind of implementation dangerous and doesn't it break the encapsulation rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The implementation for the usecase seems unusual and dangerous, because when calling a setter on a field I would **never expect** the behaviour of:

> assigns values to **other** properties

---

I would recommend to create separate functions.

1) Your field is a function anyways:

`fun stringRepresentation() = this.toString()`

2) Setting other properties:

```
parseAndSetOther(value: String)  { 
  /* parses the string and assigns values to other properties */ 
}
```

2.1) Maybe you could keep the object immutable and return a new - modified object:

```
parseAndSetOther(value: String) : MyClass { 
  /* parses the string and assigns values to other properties */ 
  return this.copy(value = "new value", ...)
}
```